# Google Hangouts Video Call: extrem jitter

Tags: video, chromium, google-hangouts

Today I joined a google hangout video meeting with Chromium. The quality was very low. With other words unusable.

It was not the wifi connection. I joined the same meeting with a mac book and there the quality was good. I switched twice during two minutes: Ubuntu Laptop (unusable), Mac (good), Ubuntu Laptop (unusable), Mac (good).

The ubuntu laptop was getting very slow. Switching between the browser and a terminal took minutes.

Version: Chromium 79.0.3945.79, running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-Bit)

Here is the output of `lshw` of my laptop: https://pastebin.com/uw8aCbGQ

What could be the reason for the very low quality on my ubuntu laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was not related to google hangout video call.

There was a custom service restarting over and over again consuming a lot of resources on the laptop.

This was not noticable until the video call started.

After disabling the service the video calls work perfectly even with Chromium. I have not tried google chrome, since the issue is resolved now.